# How to enable the FFMPEG logging?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to debug the ffmpeg. I add the following code to print logs:

```
av_log(s, AV_LOG_PANIC, fmt, ...)
```

or

```
printf("msg....")
```

But it can't work. There isn't any debug information.

Then I enable the debug build option:

```
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-debug"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-debug=0"
```

It can't work.

I'm sure that the place where I added the trace will be executed.

I just want to print some simple informations, how to do it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
void my_log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vargs)
{
    vprintf(fmt, vargs);
}
```

Set the log level and register the log callback:

```
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_ERROR);
av_log_set_callback(my_log_callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

this works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
...
}
```