# how to remove ffmpeg debug message

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm building the ffmpeg source on my Linux board. With no options, I built it like this:

./configuration

make && make install

If you build with this and run the program using C ++, you will see the following ffmpeg error message in the console window (the program runs normally, but ffmpeg itself error code [eg decode_slick_header error])

[h264 @ 0x10c0ff0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

[h264 @ 0x10c0ff0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

[h264 @ 0x10c0ff0] decode_slice_header error

[h264 @ 0x10c0ff0] no frame!

[h264 @ 0x10c0ff0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

...

I do not want to output these messages to the console window.

So we refer to the configuration document and build as follows.

./configuration --disable-logging --disable-debug
make && make install

However, the output of the build also produces an error message.

How would you like to build ffmpeg debug messages like this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `--disable-logging` stops the log from the execution of `configure`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31181618/5726027 and set level as AV_LOG_FATAL but you will lose warnings from other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this parameter to your `system("/path/ffmpeg ...");` line (or whatever you use) when calling ffmpeg executable: `-loglevel quiet`

Hope that helps.